# THREE.JS Cube Rendering

Tags: three.js, cube

Is it possible to change some stuff around with the Three/Cube rendering?

[image]

This is a rotating cube on the Y axis.
Is it possible to keep the stuff that is on the back of the cube loaded ?

Something like this
(poor drawing ftw)
Is it also possible to remove those small white lines?
I find those pretty annoying

[image]

Code I used a very long time ago. R34 or something if i am not mistaking.
Anyone knows if this is still possible in the R65?

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
    init();
    setInterval( loop, 1000 / 60 );
    function init() {
    var height = 300;
    var width = 300;
    camera = new THREE.Camera(10, height/width,10, 1000);
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var hat_materials = [
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:ImageUtils.loadTexture('crate1.png') }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:ImageUtils.loadTexture('crate1.png') }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:ImageUtils.loadTexture('crate1.png') }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:ImageUtils.loadTexture('crate1.png') }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:ImageUtils.loadTexture('crate1.png') }),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:ImageUtils.loadTexture('crate1.png') })
    ];
    hat = new THREE.Mesh( new Cube(8, 8, 8, 1, 1, hat_materials), new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial());
    hat.position.x = 0;
    hat.position.y = -10;
    hat.position.z = 0;
    scene.addObject(hat);  
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( width,height);
    document.getElementById("holder").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}
var xvar = 0;
function loop() {
    var speed = $("#speed").val() 
    xvar += Math.PI/speed
    camera.target.position.x = 0;
    camera.target.position.y = -11;
    camera.target.position.z = 0;
    camera.position.x = 0 - 100*Math.sin(xvar);
    camera.position.y = 20;
    camera.position.z = 0 - 100*Math.cos(xvar);
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making the material two sided:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:ImageUtils.loadTexture('crate1.png'),side:THREE.DoubleSide});
```

so you're code would be:

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
    init();
    setInterval( loop, 1000 / 60 );
    function init() {
    var height = 300;
    var width = 300;
    camera = new THREE.Camera(10, height/width,10, 1000);
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var hat_materials = [
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:ImageUtils.loadTexture('crate1.png') },side:THREE.DoubleSide),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:ImageUtils.loadTexture('crate1.png') },side:THREE.DoubleSide),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:ImageUtils.loadTexture('crate1.png') },side:THREE.DoubleSide),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:ImageUtils.loadTexture('crate1.png') },side:THREE.DoubleSide),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:ImageUtils.loadTexture('crate1.png') },side:THREE.DoubleSide),
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:ImageUtils.loadTexture('crate1.png') ,side:THREE.DoubleSide})
    ];
    hat = new THREE.Mesh( new Cube(8, 8, 8, 1, 1, hat_materials), new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial());
    hat.position.x = 0;
    hat.position.y = -10;
    hat.position.z = 0;
    scene.addObject(hat);  
    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( width,height);
    document.getElementById("holder").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}
var xvar = 0;
function loop() {
    var speed = $("#speed").val() 
    xvar += Math.PI/speed
    camera.target.position.x = 0;
    camera.target.position.y = -11;
    camera.target.position.z = 0;
    camera.position.x = 0 - 100*Math.sin(xvar);
    camera.position.y = 20;
    camera.position.z = 0 - 100*Math.cos(xvar);
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```